# Why do you feel ripples by sliding finger on an AC-powered macbook surface?

Tags: electricity, frequency, resonance

1. It doesn't have to be a MacBook exactly, other switched power supply powered metal case devices are good enough, but MacBook is the most common.
2. It must be AC powered; the effect disappears when unplugged.
3. Your other hand (which doesn't slide on the surface) must not touch the surface; the effect disappears when touching the surface with the other hand.
4. You must move your finger; the effect disappears when you stop.
5. The same effect can be felt by sliding on someone else who touches such a device.
6. It's definitely not a potential difference.
7. I suppose it's mechanical resonance, but can't explain.

Comment: You are assuming other people feel these effects.  I never have.

Comment: I'm sure other people feel this effect as I asked them. Have you ever tried?

Comment: Are you using a grounded power cord?

Comment: I confirm the phenomenon exists. I have experienced it, and I am curious about the nature of it. The phenomenon is rare, indicating it requires a special combination of circumstances. Another example of someone reporting the phenomenon: a forum thread with the title: '[that hard to describe vibration when you rub hour hand over something electrical](https://www.homebrewtalk.com/threads/that-hard-to-describe-vibration-feeling-when-you-rub-your-hand-over-something-electrical.703146/)' To whoever proposed to close the question: I recommend keeping this question open.

Comment: Earlier question about the same phenomenon, posted in January  2011: '[Why does my wife's skin buzz when she's using her laptop?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/why-does-my-wifes-skin-buzz-when-shes-using-her-laptop?)' Also: links to reports of the phenomenon on other fora in the comment section of this question: '[experiencing vibration when in contact with my desk computer and a rubbing a friend's arm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335022/experiencing-vibration-when-in-contact-with-my-desk-computer-and-a-rubbing-a-fri).